# LibGDX ".DT_Store" file not found error message when compiling for HTML using GWT

Tags: gwt, libgdx

On a LibGDX based project, when compiling your project for HTML (using GWT) your hidden '.DT_Store' files in your asset folder will not be deployed but will still be referenced. This causes a:

> **".DT_Store file" not found**

when you open the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the file you don't want to be included in your deploy.

This solution can be applied to any other file you want to exclude.

in your .gwt.xml file, add the following tags:

```
<set-configuration-property name="gdx.assetfilterclass" value="com.my.Package.DefaultAssetFilter" />
<set-configuration-property name="gdx.assetpath" value="../android/assets" />
```

in your HTML project, add a class:

```
package com.my.Package;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.preloader.AssetFilter;

/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright 2011 See AUTHORS file.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 ******************************************************************************/


public class DefaultAssetFilter implements AssetFilter {
    private String extension (String file) {
        String name = file;
        int dotIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (dotIndex == -1) return "";
        return name.substring(dotIndex + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept (String file, boolean isDirectory) {
        if (isDirectory && file.endsWith(".svn")) return false;
        if (isDirectory && file.endsWith(".bundle")) return false;
        if (file.endsWith(".DS_Store")) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public AssetType getType (String file) {
        String extension = extension(file).toLowerCase();
        if (isImage(extension)) return AssetType.Image;
        if (isAudio(extension)) return AssetType.Audio;
        if (isText(extension)) return AssetType.Text;
        return AssetType.Binary;
    }

    private boolean isImage (String extension) {
        return extension.toLowerCase().equals("jpg") || extension.toLowerCase().equals("jpeg") || extension.toLowerCase().equals("png") || extension.toLowerCase().equals("bmp") || extension.toLowerCase().equals("gif");
    }

    private boolean isText (String extension) {
        return extension.toLowerCase().equals("json") || extension.toLowerCase().equals("xml") || extension.equals("txt") || extension.equals("glsl")
                || extension.equals("fnt") || extension.equals("pack") || extension.equals("obj") || extension.equals("atlas")
                || extension.equals("g3dj");
    }

    private boolean isAudio (String extension) {
        return extension.toLowerCase().equals("mp3") || extension.toLowerCase().equals("ogg") || extension.toLowerCase().equals("wav");
    }

    @Override
    public String getBundleName (String file) {
        return "assets";
    }
}
```